# How to integrate $\frac{1}{z^{1/2}}$ with respect to complex variable $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

I'm looking at example 7.54 in the book by Ponnusamy, available publicly [here](http://files.referentematematico.webnode.es/200000009-c51c0c70b6/Ponnusamy%20S.,%20Silverman%20H.%20Complex%20Variables%20with%20Applications%20(Birkhauser,%202006)(520s)_MCc_.pdf), on page 240 (249 in the pdf viewer).

> **Example 7.54.** Consider $$\int_{|z|=1} f(z)\ dz,\quad f(z)=1/z^{1/2}.$$
>   Then $z=0$ is a branch point of $f(z)$.  If we choose principal branch, then $$z^{1/2}=e^{(1/2)\operatorname{Log}z}=e^{(1/2)(\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg} z)}$$ so that for $z=e^{i\theta}$, we have $z^{1/2}=e^{i(1/2)\operatorname{Arg}z}=e^{(1/2)i\theta}$ and $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{ie^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta/2}}\ d\theta=i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\theta/2}\ d\theta=4i.$$

In the above example, I do not understand two things:

1) Does $\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta/2}}$ reduce to $e^{-i\theta/2}$, generally?

2) Why are the integration limits $\pi$ and $-\pi$ and not $0$ and $2 \pi$?  (as you'll notice, the limits of integration affect the result if the answer to 1) is "No".)

Comment: Check the definition of principal branch.

Comment: Because I have seen integration limits from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ used when the function is $log z$ or $z^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha < 1$, but otherwise I have seen integration limits from $0$ to $2 \pi$:  1) Do you use principal branch any time the function is multivalued? 2) And hence do you only use integration limits from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ when the function is multivalued?

Answer (score 1):

1) $ \frac{e^{2a}}{e^{a}}=e^{2a}e^{-a}=e^{2a-a}=e^a.$

2) A possible parametrization of $\{z: |z|=1\}$ is $z( \theta)=e^{i \theta}$ for $\theta \in [- \pi, \pi].$

Comment: Right, so then why for 1) in the example does it show $e^{-a}$ instead of $e^{a}$?.

Comment: 2)  And does the parameterization need to be from $-\pi$ to $\pi$?  Or can it be from $0$ to $2\pi$?  and what would the integral look like if it were from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: do my questions make sense?  Thanks.